# Traveling to the U.S. after a 10 Year Ban

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen, but in 2005 I overstayed my time in the US for about a year and left on my own in June 2005. I tried entering back into the U.S. last year and was informed that I had a 10 year ban against my name which would expire in June 2015. What do I have to do to re enter after the ban expires? Do I have to show them any specific thing for my re entry?

Comment: Plan for a lengthy questioning as to the purpose of your visit and whether you will actually leave the US on time.

Comment: Thank you, do have have to show them anything specifics?

Comment: What can you show that will prove that you do not intend to overstay again?  Bring that.

Comment: I believe that you actually didn't have a ban, because Canadian citizens who are admitted without an I-94 (which is the usual case) do not automatically accrue "unlawful presence" on a given date because they have no I-94 date to exceed. And if you had no "unlawful presence", you didn't have an unlawful presence ban upon leaving the US.

Comment: @user102008 that sounds like an extremely tenuous line of reasoning.  Weighing it against the evidence that suggests the OP did have a ban, namely, that the OP was told there was a ban, presumably by a CBP officer, I can only conclude that your reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: @phoog: What I said is not reasoning. It is the official policy that defines "unlawful presence".

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no specific thing you have to do.

As always for foreigners entering, there is no guarantee of entry. It is at the discretion of the officer. Your past history of overstay can be a negative factor in their consideration.